# Which instructions do I use to be able to use UART directly on my STM32F107 microcontroller?

Tags: stm32, c, uart, rs485

I've tried to figure this out on my own but after almost a week I'm still at more or less the same place where I started. So, I have an STM32F107 microcontroller on a board, which is linked to another STM32 via a RS485 bus using UART. I know the bus works, because I have hooked it up to a terminal and I can see the data I am sending through it. The real issue is trying to get the other STM32 to respond so I can put it in bootloader mode and reprogram it.

I was told I needed to just put the data I wanted to send in the USART3_DR_REG (since I'm using USART 3 for communication between boards). And after checking whether the transmission is complete, I immediately flip the R/T signals back into receiver mode to get the response, which I can find in the DR register again. However, I found that I have to send some data packets several times before I get a response, and that always messes up my instructions. Is there a trick to it ? Something that I haven't seen yet ?

Here's my code so far :

```
    while(1)
    {
        Wait(S_TIME, 1);

        while(result == 0)
        {
            write_uart_byte(0x7F);

            result = read_uart_byte();//USART3_DR_REG & 0xFF;
        }
        if(result == 0x79)
        {
            write_uart_byte(0x43);
            write_uart_byte(0xBC);
            read_uart(1, &result);
            if(result == 0x79);
            {
                write_uart_byte(0xFF);
                write_uart_byte(0x00);
                read_uart(1, &result);
                if(result == 0x79)
                {
                    GPIOB_ODR_BIT_9_BB = 1;
                    Wait(MS_TIME, 500);
                    GPIOB_ODR_BIT_9_BB = 0;
                    Wait(MS_TIME, 500);
                }
            }
        }
        else if(result == 0x1F)
        {
            GPIOB_ODR_BIT_9_BB = 1;
        }
    }
```

The functions write_uart, write_uart_byte, read_uart and read_uart_byte are just to establish the link with UART. Reading is as simple as reading the DR register and only taking the lower 8 bits (DR is 9 bits long), and writing is first toggling the "master send, slave receive" mode before writing the data in the DR register and flipping back into "master receive, slave send" mode.

I appreciate any answers and comments.

There's an LED on PB9.

Here's a schematic of the project. It's for a battery management system, so the slave has to have a separate ground, since it's going to be used for measuring a number of cells in the battery.
[image]

Update : I narrowed it down to timing issues, whenever I switch the R/T signals. Sending data by itself isn't a problem, but it's trying to catch the answers that gives me trouble. Does this sound familiar to anyone ? I can ask another question dedicated to this if need be.

Comment: Do you have half duplex (2 data wires) or full duplex (2 transmit and 2 receive wires)?

Comment: It's half duplex. Two data wires, for the two differential signals of the RS485 bus.

Comment: OK. And you are using the standard STM32 built-in bootloader on the other MCU? How does the bootloader  know it is connected to a half-duplex bus in order to control the transmit enable line?

Comment: Yup, no other bootloader involved. I have a code that's going to use all the standard commands, but I need to make sure I can actually communicate before using that library. The other board doesn't really know it's connected by half-duplex, it just sees a UASRT line on its end. The line piloting is all done by the master board.

Comment: So the master STM32 will also control the transmit enable of the target MCU? So the boards share what pins? Do they also share ground? Can you please draw a diagram?

Comment: Added the diagram to show what I'm working on.

Comment: If there is no common ground how it is supposed to work?

Comment: There's galvanic isolators between the microcontroller and transceiver on the slave board ,that's the dotted line I drew.. I should have mentioned it, my bad.

Comment: So is there a ground reference between the non-isolated parts of both transceivers and for the driver enable? We can't guess what the problem is if we don't have information.

Comment: There's a specific ground for the slave microcontroller, which is the part that is plugged between cells (it's not 0V because that would make a short-circuit with the other slaves' grounds), which is different from the ground used by the other isolated part of the slave and shared by the master card.

Comment: So there is a ground wire between the bus sides of the two tranceivers on the boards? And it is also the ground for the slave TX enable? So master MCU can control both the master transmit enable and slave trasmit enable? Are the enables separate IOs or same IO? Are the transceivers always in receiver enable mode? Any pull-up or pull-downs on any pins? Is RS485 bus terminated and has it got failsafe biasing? Which RS485 transceivers are used and how they are connected? It would be simpler if you would post the schematics, not a block diagram. And code too.

Comment: The reason I'm not doing so is because I'm not sure if I'm allowed to post the entire schematic... At least from my company's pov. But I'm also sure it's not hardware related, because I am able to talk to the bootloader if I don't look for its responses.

Comment: The transmission flag is set, when the output buffer (DR) is empty, not when the whole transmission is done. Since a shift register has to send bits after that, you are probably switching RS485 transceiver into RX mode quite fast, before the whole transmission is done.

Comment: @TirdadSadriNejad I see what you mean. So how long should the extra wait be ?

Comment: @DexTr: Don't think about "extra wait", think about looking at a status flag for the event you care about (transmitter idle) not the (transmitter buffer ready to accept more data).  You want bit 6 of your USART status register, Tirdad's comment relates to bit 7.

Comment: @BenVoigt Well I exactly meant TC bit. It seems the OP is using TXE which is fine for normal bytes, but needs to check TC after last byte to assure a complete transmission, then change direction of RS485 transceiver.

Comment: @TirdadSadriNejad: I don't see anything in the question that suggests he is checking TXE, but he does say he is checking for "transmission is complete" which suggests TC.  In any case it would be good for him to double-check that he's checking the flag that's appropriate for this, which is TC (bit 6)

Comment: Yes, I am checking TC. USART_SR_BIT_6. I think I found my problem though, it was just that I'm flipping back and forth too fast for data to make it.